# How to get inserted id using Spring Jdbctemplate.update(String sql, obj...args)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, last-insert-id

I'm using Jdbctemplate and I need the inserted id of a query.
I read that I have to build a particular PreparedStatement and use GeneratedKeyHolder object.

The problem is that in my application all inserts method uses this JdbcTemplate update method:

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(SQL_INSERT,param1,param2,param3,...);
```

Is there another way to get the inserted id without refactoring all daos?

Comment: If you're using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, then it's very easy. Check https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/spring-jdbc-insert-auto-generated-key.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) and [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) You have two choices:

use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`'s [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-) method.

use `JdbcTemplate`'s [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-) method.

There are also some other methods available which will populate the keys to the given  [GeneratedKeyHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html), it's up to you which one suits your needs.

**EDIT**

For e.g. using JdbcTemplate:

```
GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(NAME, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?) ", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setString(1, "SomeName");
        statement.setString(2, "SomeValue");
        return statement;
    }
}, holder);

long primaryKey = holder.getKey().longValue();
```

Comment: Ok but how to wrap existing code? (param1,param2,param3...args)

Comment: If you'd choose NamedParameterJdbcTemplate you'll have to create SqlParameterSource, otherwise with JdbcTemplate you'd have to use PreparedStatementCreator. Give me a sec, I'll update my answer giving an example.

Comment: MMh... so I have to refactor all daos... now other way?

Comment: What spring documentation states - yes, there is no other way.

Comment: Is the statement with this example code recreated for each call? For example if I have many inserts should I use a different storing the PreparedStatement?

Comment: If you'd have many inserts you have to use [batchUpdate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter-). You can have a look at examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/)

Comment: in case you  use NEWID(), sql server , how would you handle ?

Comment: How can we get the same value in Batch Update?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for PostgreSQL, the holder returns all the attributes. Here is a link to the solution in PostgreSQL [Spring: How to use KeyHolder with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771306/spring-how-to-use-keyholder-with-postgresql)